# Can a Lyapunov Function's Derivative be Negative Semi-Definite Outside a Contour?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lyapunov-functions

A question I recently came across challenged the definition I learned, and keep finding, about Lyapunov Stability:

"Given the system:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x(1-x^{2})+y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=y(1-y^{2})-x$$
Prove the existence of a limit cycle. Hint: $v(x,y)=x^{2}+y^{2}$ may be helpful."

Using the fact we can assert the existence of a limit cycle with the Lyapunov Stability Theorem, I assumed $v(x,y)$ was the provided Lyapunov function, and went on to show $\frac{dv}{dt}$ is negative semi-definite $\forall (x,y)\neq(0,0)$, the fixed point (implying $(0,0)$ is stable and thus has a limit cycle rotating around). Showing the simplified results:
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=2(x^{2}-x^{4}+y^{2}-y^{4})$$
But $\frac{dv}{dt}$ is only negative semi-definite outside the contour $x^{2}-x^{4}+y^{2}-y^{4}=0$.

Regarding the Lyapunov Stability Theorem, did the question statement give an incorrect Lyapunov function? Or am I misinterpretting the theorem altogether?

As always, a big thank you to those who spend their time helping to resolve and explain these questions.

Comment: Lyapunov's theorem makes a statement about equilibrium points not limit cycles. However, you are on the right track. The set $x^{2}-x^{4}+y^{2}-y^{4}=0$ forms a "four leaf clover" contour. The region where $x^{2}-x^{4}+y^{2}-y^{4} < 0$ is outside and $>0$ is inside the four leaf clover. Using $\frac{dv}{dt}$, think about what happens to points in both those regions over time, what do they approach?

Comment: OKAY! So I believe I understand: (EDIT: I hit the ENTER key before finishing the comment)

So Lyapunov functions are meant to "suggest" the solution trajectory.
For a negative definite $\frac{dv}{dt}$ excluding the fixed point, this guarantees all trajectories go inwards to the fixed point.
For negative semi-definite, it's better to think of 2 regions: A bounded, dense region $R$ around the fixed point, and some annulus $\Omega$ surrounding $R$. Such a derived Lyapunov function is positive in $R$ and negative in $\Omega$ to SUGGEST a particle stays in some annulus, thus limit cycle.